# Longpolling(comet) solution for Rails as a mobile backend(no js)

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, mobile, long-polling

Is it possible to organize real-time connection interaction rails app and mobile client(ios, android)? There are many js solutions based socket.io, but I have no ideas how connect them with mobile clients. Maybe there are pure rails alternatives for this? I know that rails 4 will have live streaming feature, but I need solution for 3.2.

Thanks for any help!

ps: nginx+passenger as a web-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that pusher.com is the best solution. Socket.io separate server also tales place